# How to create a SPACE between word and open bracket in list of sentences

Tags: python, regex, list, nltk, python-re

In below list, there are actually two dupes. But due to difference of SPACE between second word of sentence and (, its treating them as unique sentences.

By using Python - Regular Expressions, how to create addition space between words. (example: 1st item) 'United States(US)', should be changed to 'United States (US)'   (same as 2nd item)

```
listx = 
['United States(US)',
 'United States (US)',
 'New York(NY)',
 'New York (NY)']
```

**Expected Output list is**

```
['United States (US)',
 'United States (US)',
 'New York (NY)',
 'New York (NY)']
```

Actually, i am trying eliminate duplicate sentences from the list and considering this is one of the approach by making the sentences similar first. 
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for a letter immediately followed by an open parentheses

```
>>> [re.sub(r'(\w)\(', r'\1 (', i) for i in listx]
['United States (US)',
 'United States (US)',
 'New York (NY)',
 'New York (NY)']
```

To remove the duplicates you can create a `set` from this generator expression

```
>>> set(re.sub(r'(\w)\(', r'\1 (', i) for i in listx)
{'United States (US)', 'New York (NY)'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You can use [**`re.sub`**](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/re.html#re.sub) here.

```
listx = ['United States(US)', 'United States (US)', 'New York(NY)', 'New York (NY)']

[re.sub(r'.(\(.*\))',r' \1',i) for i in listx]
# ['United State (US)', 'United States (US)', 'New Yor (NY)', 'New York (NY)']
```

Regex pattern explanation:

- `.` to match any character
- `(` start of group bracket
- `\(` match `(`
- `.*` match greedily.
- `' \1'` sub the match group with space the matched group.
- [`regex live demo`](https://regex101.com/r/p0oUKR/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
    new_listx = ["{} {}".format(re.match('(.*)(\(.*\))', i).group(1).rstrip() ,re.match('(.*)(\(.*\))', i).group(2)) for i in listx]
    print(new_listx)
```

Output

```
['United States (US)', 'United States (US)', 'New York (NY)', 'New York (NY)']
```

The regex is splitting the text to 2 groups one is before the () and the second in the () after that it's trimming the space form the right of the first group.

then you can do

```
print(set(new_listx))
```

and you will get a unique values set.

```
{'New York (NY)', 'United States (US)'}
```